# Javascript function doesn't work with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I am new to OO JavaScript, and have tried writing a plugin which allows me so create multiple instances of "pretty selects" which can have custom html formatted within...

the issue im having is that when i add multiple instances on the page, one returns undefined or odd values....

Here is my JS

```
function selectify(options) {
      var $elem = $(options.target),
          $button = $elem.find('button');
          open = false;

      function getVal() {
         return $elem.find('input:checked').val();
      }
      function setVal(val) {
        $elem.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $elem.find('input[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked','checked').parent().addClass('active');
      }
      function toggle() {
        if(open) {
            open = false;
            $elem.removeClass('open');
            $button.attr('aria-pressed','false');
        } else {
            open = true;
            //$elem.find('.active input').focus();
            $elem.addClass('open');
            $button.attr('aria-pressed','true');
        }
      }
      $button.attr('aria-pressed','false');
      $elem.find('input:checked').parent().addClass('active')
      $elem.find('label').click(function() {
        setVal($(this).find('input').val());
        if(open) toggle();
      });
      $button.click(function() {
        toggle();
      })

        $(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
            if(open) {
                switch(e.keyCode) {
                    case 40:
                        //down
                      if(!$elem.find('.active').is('label:last-child')) setVal($elem.find('.active').next('label').find('input').val());
                    break;
                    case 38:
                      //up
                      if($elem.find('.active').index()>1) setVal($elem.find('.active').prev('label').find('input').val());
                    break;
                    case 27:
                        toggle();
                    break;
                }
            }
        })

      return {
        getVal: getVal,
        setVal: setVal,
        open: open,
        toggle: toggle
      }
    }

    var x = new selectify({
      target:'.target2'
    });

    var y = new selectify({
      target:'.target'
    });
```

and this is the html

```
<fieldset class="selectify target">

<button aria-label="open select">▼</button>
    <!--legend>Donut Type</legend-->
<label>
          <input type="radio" value="1" name="flavour" />
        Red
</label>
<label>
          <input type="radio" value="2" name="flavour" checked="checked" />
        Blue
</label>
<label>
          <input type="radio" value="3" name="flavour" />
        Green
</label>
<label>
          <input type="radio" value="4" name="flavour" />
        Yellow
</label>
<label>
          <input type="radio" value="5" name="flavour" />
        Cat
</label>
</fieldset>
```

I have a working example on CodePen if that helps?

http://codepen.io/ben-walters/pen/fbIya

Thanks in advance guys and girls!

Comment: I tried your codepen. Both drop-downs seem to work. What is it supposed to do differently? If it's returning the wrong thing, how can I tell?

Comment: Cheers for checking it out.

if you notice the first one doesnt seem to load properly, ie, the value is not correctly. It should have the checked value displayed

Comment: From elements INPUT type="radio" with the same name "flavour" only one can be "checked". So if you have your fieldset twice, only the last <input type="radio" value="2" name="flavour" checked="checked" /> is really checked.

Comment: Cheers Axel.... that fixed it! I was looking so hard at the JS, i completely forgot to check my HTML was legit. Thanks!